# Software to do Duplo train track layout?

Tags: trains, duplo, tracks

Anyone know a way to create with a software DUPLO train track layout?

The only thing I found is:
http://www.anyrail.com/index_en.html

It's a bit overkill for what I need and it's $US60, although the limited version can be used free.

LEGO has a track planner for non DUPLO track.
http://www.lego.com/en-us/city/trains/track-planner

If I can't find something, I'll probably try to do it myself (I have a background of tools programmer in video game industry)

Comment: I've used a program called WinRail that again is probably overkill for what you need, but was great for me with Brio, HO/OO and Scalextric. I know it has some LEGO elements in it, I'll check tonight if it has DUPLO as well...

Comment: Rather belated response - No, my WinRail10 instance only had LEGO Trains and LEGO 9V Trains, but I think the points were off in both of those - at least, they don't match the points I've floating around somewhere.

Comment: I asked question on here about Lego System track layout, I've 1st type blue rails. The points like 2× straight with 1 end having 2 track side by side. Later = points like part of circle with straight tangent. So need to know what Duplo points are like, then 1 of System track software should do.

Comment: See has both parallel & curved out points, 2 sizes track length, like more advance than System rails?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would recommend [BlueBrick](http://bluebrick.lswproject.com/), which is a versatile LEGO layout editor by Alban Nanty.

Apperently it has Duplo parts too, so I believe it should meet your needs. It can actually do much more for your layout planning needs (including modular tables if your club has some, for example), so maybe you'll consider it overkill as well, but since it's specifically made for LEGO layout I think you should be hapy with it.

Disclaimer: I have never used it for Duplo myself - if you do, feel free to share your experience with us in a comment.

Comment: BlueBrick work!  It's not perfect, but it's free and open source which is really great!  Thansk a lot!

Answer (score 6):

You can use **RailModeller Express** or **RailModeller Pro** on macOS.
Both feature LEGO tracks (regular and Duplo):

http://www.railmodeller.com/libraries.html

Comment: ..the _Express_ edition being completely free to use :-)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for mentioning our macOS apps!
You can also use our free app *RailModeller Express* for LEGO Duplo trains: http://www.railmodeller.com/express-edition-en.html

For iPads please check our new iOS app:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/play-well-d-train/id1231936324?mt=8&at=1000lp7a

Answer (score 3):

mayTracks - Lego Duplo Track Creator

A bit late - but there is an app for Windows and/or MAC to create DUPLO tracks with most known DUPLO bricks. I tested it and it works nice. In minutes and with a view clicks - I created large track plans. There is a PDF export too.

https://maytracks.maydorf.com